# Syntax Issue: Trying to Push Node onto Queue

Tags: c++, templates, queue, push, binary-search-tree

I've got a binary search tree composed of two parameters. I need to implement a breadth-first list of everything in the tree, and while I think I understand what I need to write, I'm having some trouble with the syntax.

```
#include <queue>

template <class T> class Node {};

template <class T> class Tree 
{
  Node<T> *root;

  void foo()
  {
    std::queue<Node<T> > myqueue;
    myqueue.push(root<T>); // error here
  }
};
```

Comment: Note that to improve the question even further, it would be relevant to  explain what the error actually is (i.e., say that it does not compile, and copy paste the compiler error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the member `root` is of type `Node<T> *`. But your queue `myqueue` contains elements of type `Node<T>`. Try this instead:

```
std::queue<Node<T> *> myqueue;     // note the different type here
myqueue.push(root);
```

Comment: @Mock Happy to help :-) Note: do not take too personally the "on hold" on your question. But if you want to avoid this in the future, try to create a Minimal Example as suggested ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ). Not only it will be easier for us to help, but in addition it is likely that through this process you'll find the answer to your question yourself, and you will learn much more effectively.

Comment: Noted, thank you. I'm aware that this amount of code is somewhat overkill but kept asking previous questions and getting told to include more of the code :P

Comment: @Mock The thing is that the code posted has to be *minimal* AND *complete*. This is really important. By "minimal", we do not want you to post only the relevant part of the code. Instead, you must try to create a completely new project, with as few lines of code as possible, but that exhibits the same issue you're having (and post this minimal complete example). This is not just for SO, this is exactly what good programmers do each time they encounter a weird behaviour they don't understand. It is an important skill to learn. See: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Mock See my edit, since it's much better to understand the concept with an example :-)

Comment: Alright, thank you. I would have assumed that was too little code, but I definitely don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: @Mock The less code (as long as it still exhibits the error), the better. It helps you to pin point *exactly* where the problem is. In that case, experienced developers can see what's the problem is in about 5sec, and therefore you would get a fast answer!

Comment: @Mock Now that makes it a good question+answer that can be useful to future users as well :-)